# Preferred Wordpress video format?

Tags: video-player

I'm developing a Wordpress blog for a client who needs to embed their own video files. Flash video was our format of choice until recently, but is there a preferred format for Wordpress? One that easily integrates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Codex lists several core-supported oEmbed sites](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#Okay.2C_So_What_Sites_Can_I_Embed_From.3F) (including a few being added in 3.5):

- [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/) (only public videos and playlists - "unlisted" and "private" videos will not embed)
- [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/) (note older versions of WP have issues with https embeds, just remove the s from the https to fix)
- [DailyMotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/)
- [blip.tv](http://blip.tv/)
- [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) (both videos and images)
- [Viddler](http://www.viddler.com/)
- [Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/)
- [Qik](http://qik.com/)
- [evision3](http://revision3.com/)
- [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/)
- [Photobucket](http://photobucket.com/)
- [PollDaddy](http://www.polldaddy.com/)
- [WordPress.tv](http://wordpress.tv/) (only [http://videopress.com/ VideoPress]-type videos for the time being)
- [SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com/) (WordPress 3.0+)
- [FunnyOrDie.com](http://www.funnyordie.com/) (WordPress 3.0+)
- [Twitter](http://twitter.com) (WordPress 3.4+)
- [Instagram](http://instagram.com) (WordPress 3.5+)
- [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net) (WordPress 3.5+)
- [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com/) (WordPress 3.5+)

Comment: So there is no native way to embed your own videos directly into a blog post?

Comment: oEmbed **is** the way to embed videos manually into a blog post. Please read the linked Codex entry.